# Running a script that executes every 5 seconds consumes a lot of memory or it is fine?

Tags: shell-script

I would like to create a cron-like script with an infinite loop that executes forever.

My goal is to check if a a file is created, if it is then the file is executed and deleted... so it only executes the loop if the file exists.

My question is: Would this consume a lot of memory? Is it a bad idea or it is fine? If it is a bad idea then what solution do I have? If it is fine, how far can I go? is it scalable? How many scripts can I create and still be safe?

Comment: If your script is something like `#!/bin/bash\n[[ -e foo.sh ]] && ./foo.sh` then the memory and CPU usage will be minimal and you could probably run dozens of these. Five seconds seems excessive to me but that really is determined by your workflow. Major memory requirements will be determined by what the script executes. It likely would be better overall to put the script as a service and in a infinite loop to avoid continuous process creations.

Comment: thanks ..I think the service is a good tip to consider.

Comment: A script with an infinite loop is almost precisely the OPPOSITE of a Cron script. It shouldn't use a lot of memory but it will use a lot of CPU and io. Using inotify would be a better way of achieving the desired result - I suggest you search for 'incron'

Comment: I assume that the script will always finish in less than 5 seconds. Even is that is the expected case, I would suggest putting in a locking mechanism in place to prevent multiple simultaneous executions. Using `flock` may be the most robust but pid files will work in a pinch.

Comment: @symcbean How will `[[ -e file ]] && ./execute file; sleep 5` manage to use a lot of CPU? Yes, not optimal and `inotify` is a better solution if the script can be written to support it,

Comment: @symcbean I am not familiar with `incron`. I will have to look into it as a useful service for my users.

Comment: inotifywait/inotifywatch and running a script constantly sound like a much more rational idea.